# ExtJS 4.2.0 gridpanel inside viewport rendering extra column

Tags: extjs4.2

I am using ExtJS 4.2.0 and testing on google chrome 42.0.2311.152 m. Here
is my fiddle:('ct' is nothing but just a div)

http://jsfiddle.net/5zpx4556/

```
    Ext.define('SimpleGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.SimpleGrid',
    columns: [
        {
            dataIndex: 'name'
        }, {

            dataIndex: 'status'

        }, {

            dataIndex: 'enabled'
        }
    ],

    store: {
        fields: ['sex', 'name', 'status', 'enabled'],

        data: [
            { sex: 'male', name: 'Tom', status: 'Available', enabled: true }

        ]
    }
});
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
    renderTo:'ct',
            items: [

                {
                    xtype: 'SimpleGrid'

                }

            ]
        });
```

I have already posted this as a bug in the sencha forum but would be great if someone could provide a workaround for this scenario if at all it is a bug.
Not sure of the align:'stretch' has anything to do with it but there should be no reason to render the extra column.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a column, it is just empty space left after rendering three columns. Add `flex:1` to one of the columns to fill the width.

Comment: Oh I see what's going on. Thanks Saki! :)